# How to determine the network latency between two servers?

Tags: c#, networking, latency

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uBZt.png)
I am trying to obtain the latency time between 2 servers. So how would it be possible to obtain it in milliseconds?
Is round trip time calculated while pinging the same as latency time?

Comment: If what you are trying to do is finding the latency of 2 severs and you can't send a ping  from one to another, as far I know thats not possible from a 3* server

Comment: I've left an answer with code over at the linked duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236422/397817

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just ping the other server, it's the latency.
See this question for examples: [Using ping in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800958/using-ping-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the question, ping returns me RTT with average, maximum and minimum time. So which time exactly would be required to calculate latency?

Comment: You probably want to take the average, you've sent 3 ping requests and they might return a bit different responses, so taking the average will reflect the most accurate estimation.